# PDO Query inserting twice in a row

Tags: php, mysql

```
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
        $pay_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
        $payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];


        // Personal information
        $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
        $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];

        if (isset($_POST['payer_business_name'])) 
            $business = $_POST['payer_business_name'];
        else
            $business = "";

        $address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
        $address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
        $address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
        $address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
        $address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
        $address_country_code = $_POST['address_country_code'];

        if (isset($_POST['contact_phone']))
            $payer_phone =  $_POST['contact_phone'];
        else
            $payer_phone = "";    

$array = array(
                ":txn_id" => $txn_id,
                ":payer_firstname" => $firstname,
                ":payer_lastname" => $lastname,
                ":payer_business" => $business,
                ":payer_email" => $payer_email,
                ":payer_country_code" => $address_country_code,
                ":payer_country" => $address_country,
                ":payer_state" => $address_state,
                ":payer_city" => $address_city,
                ":payer_zip" => $address_zip,
                ":payer_street" => $address_street,
                ":payer_phone" => $payer_phone,
                ":payer_type" => $payment_type,
                ":item_name" => $item_name,
                ":item_number" => $item_number,
                ":payment_amount" => $payment_amount,
                ":payment_status" => $payment_status,
                ":payment_currency" => $payment_currency,
                ":date" => $pay_date,
                ":ip" => $client->IP()
        );


        $prepare = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO transactions ( t_num, t_payer_firstname, t_payer_lastname, t_payer_business, t_payer_email, t_payer_country_code, t_payer_country, t_payer_state, t_payer_city, t_payer_street, t_payer_zip, t_payer_phone, t_payer_type, t_name, t_hex, t_price, t_status, t_currency, t_date, t_ip ) VALUES ( :txn_id, :payer_firstname, :payer_lastname, :payer_business, :payer_email, :payer_country_code, :payer_country, :payer_state, :payer_city, :payer_zip, :payer_street, :payer_phone, :payer_type, :item_name, :item_number, :payment_amount, :payment_status, :payment_currency, :date, :ip ) ");

        if ($prepare->execute($array)) {
            $msg = "<strong>Congratulations " . $lastname . ", " . $firstname . "!</strong>
            <br/>Your order has been placed and will be processed within 12-24 hours!
            <br/><br/>
            <b>Transaction #:</b> " . $txn_id . "<br/>
            <b>Item Name:</b> " . $item_name . "<br/>
            <b>Item Number:</b> " . $item_number . "<br/><br/><br/>
            <b>First Name:</b> " . $first_name . "<br/>
            <b>Last Name:</b> " . $last_name . "<br/>

            ";
        }
```

For some reason, my query will insert itself twice.... I don't know if it's the if statement checking if rowCount is greater than 0 that's the issue or I'm blind about something?

EDIT: Edited the post to show the $_POST variables.

Comment: That's a squirrely one ... it looks fine to me.  The only suggestion I can offer is that you might want to use `$conn->lastInsertId()` rather than `$execute->rowCount()` to check the success of your query?  Maybe there's something in the intervening code you may not have shown here?

Comment: The thing is, this is the only thing in my code that requires database work atm... This is my first actual SQL statement so there's no real intervening code that can even allow this.

Thanks for your suggestion on lastInsertId, I have started using that now but I still somehow get the same issue :(

Comment: How about a little higher?  I'm assuming that there'll be some kind of conditional expression that needs to be satisfied in order for this code to be executed - could the problem be there?

Comment: I have updated the thread with the code above it, but it shouldn't have any effect on the query itself.

Comment: Well, the good news is that it's not any of that code. Somehow this block is being executed twice.  I know how easy it is to get tunnel vision and focus on the wrong thing - particularly once it starts to get frustrating.  Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: How is processed your request? Do you use MVC or your source just from script_name_file.php?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you are executing the query twice because below is the code i am trying with and it always insert one row.

And also check every include, index file. Or restart mysql.

```
<?php
$array = array(
        ":txn_id" => "1",
        ":payer_firstname" => "2",
        ":payer_lastname" => "3",
        ":payer_business" => "4",
        ":payer_email" => "5",
        ":payer_country_code" => "6",
        ":payer_country" => "7",
        ":payer_state" => "8",
        ":payer_city" => "9",
        ":payer_zip" => "10",
        ":payer_street" => "11",
        ":payer_phone" => "12",
        ":payer_type" => "13",
        ":item_name" => "14",
        ":item_number" => "15",
        ":payment_amount" => "16",
        ":payment_status" => "17",
        ":payment_currency" => "18",
        ":date" => "19",
        ":ip" => "20"
);

 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', "root", "123456");

 $prepare = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO transactions ( t_num,   
 t_payer_firstname, t_payer_lastname, t_payer_business, t_payer_email, 
 t_payer_country_code, t_payer_country, t_payer_state, t_payer_city,   
 t_payer_street, t_payer_zip, t_payer_phone, t_payer_type, t_name,  
 t_hex, t_price, t_status, t_currency, t_date, t_ip ) VALUES ( :txn_id, 
 :payer_firstname,
 :payer_lastname,
 :payer_business, 
 :payer_email,  
 :payer_country_code, 
 :payer_country, 
 :payer_state, 
 :payer_city,  
 :payer_zip,  
 :payer_street, 
 :payer_phone, 
 :payer_type, 
 :item_name, 
 :item_number,   
 :payment_amount, 
 :payment_status, 
 :payment_currency, 
 :date, 
 :ip ) ");

$execute = $prepare->execute($array);

if ($execute) {
    echo 'good';
}
```

?>

Comment: I've done all you have said above and I'm still getting the issue ... Maybe it's something with my $_POST's?